# Bulma remove variable

Tags: css, sass, frontend, web-frontend, bulma

I'm using Bulma. I have set linear gradient for body background in mystyle.scss, but the default html background-color which has been set to white, is visible under the page. I need to remove that default html backgronud-color.

There was a `$html-background-color` variable in mystyle.scss file, and it was ok with any color I did set for that and there was no white area then. But as I want to use linear gradient, I commented that line and set body background instead.

What should I do?! Even overriding that in the mystyle.scss file didn't help.

The webpage:

[image]

The related line in mystyle.css from Bulma's default variable:

[image]